# R dataframe analytic function return top n rows that account for k% of some metric

Tags: r, analytics, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe which I need to subset in a way that will return top n rows where these n rows account for k% (assume k=50%) of sales/profit.
This is how my df head looks like:

```
    orders     sales    profit        pm       bbr      asins
1 1.545455  6.614545  1.596364 0.2011571   0.00000 B0017YQMQ4
2 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000       NaN  83.35636 B004OC7N3C
3 1.636364 47.372727 11.078182 0.2338515 100.00000 B001PMAJZI
4 1.272727 54.663636 15.858182 0.2901048 100.00000 B00GUO2W1K
5 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000       NaN 100.00000 B00GUOGUYA
6 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000       NaN  54.83000 B00KO2FYAK
```

Any ideas how to do that elegantly (no loops) are welcomed and most appreciated. thanks

UPDATE:
I have a code snippet that does this in a loop. However, would be nice to switch it with a *apply function or something like that

```
# given parameter pareto, e.g. 50% sales, return n products that account for this metric
top_sales_products <- list()
aggr_sales_percent <- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(SA1_sorted_sales)){
  aggr_sales_percent <- aggr_sales_percent +  SA1_sorted_sales$sales_ratio[i]
  top_sales_products <- list(top_sales_products,SA1_sorted_sales$asin)
  if (aggr_sales_percent >= config$metrics_params$sales_pareto){
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you try by yourself?

Comment: 50% of the `sum(sales/profit)`?

Comment: I divided the sales by sum(sales), then in a loop, I aggregated  the sales ratio until reaches a threshold, then returned the list of products. Not elegant and quite costly from performance wise

Comment: comment to  LyzandeR : 50% of sales or 50% of profit (2 different cases, however they're identical in logic. For this case, let's go for the 'sales')